# Select parent but order by certain child with dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I'am trying to write following in Dynamic-linq. I have following statement in ordinary linq

```
var result = DBContext.Report
     .Include(h => h.ReportRoleMemberships)
     .Join(DBContext.ReportRoleMemberships.Where(Rrm =>Rrm.ValidTo==null && Rrm.UserId==userId),
           t=>t.Id,
           y=>y.Report_Id,
           (t,y) => new { Ha=t, Rrm=y })
     .OrderBy(h => h.Rrm.ReportRoleValue);
```

userId is a int with the UserId in the code above.

I want to sort on ReportRoleValue and feels this feel a little bit over the top, but I havent a clue how I should write this is dynamic linq , since it is orderby on one-to-many parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a navigation property from `ReportRoleMemberships` to `Reports`, you can turn the query around and by that remove the separate `Join`, e.g.:

```
var result = DBContext.ReportRoleMemberships
     .Include(h => h.Report)
     .Where(Rrm => Rrm.ValidTo == null && Rrm.UserId == userId)
     .OrderBy(h => h.ReportRoleValue);
```

This query selects the entries from `ReportRoleMemberships` and applies the conditions to them and also populates the `Report` part so that you retrieve both the `ReportRoleMembership` and `Report` information in one query.

Comment: Yes there is a navigation property on report to ReportRoleMembership
DBContext.Reports.Include(t=>t.ReportMembership).Where(h => (h.ReportRoleMemberships.Any(q=>  q.ValidTo == null && q.UserId== userId))).OrderBy(h => h.ReportRoleMemberships.FirstOrDefault().ReportRoleValue); If I do it likes that it takes obscene time and I find it even harder to transform it to dynamic linq.

Comment: Is there a navigation property from `ReportRoleMemberships` to `Reports`? @JerkerPihl

Comment: From Report to ReportRoleMembership, one report can have many reportrolememberships and one ReportRoleMembership  can only have one Report. Yes it is. But I need the reports also returned when sorting on the ReportRoleValue.

Comment: Due to the `.Include(h => h.Report)` the reports are also retrieved when you filter the role memberships and sort by role membership properties. So after you have executed the query, the `Report` navigation property is already loaded (eager loading) and you can access each report for a role membership.